# How to have 1 while loop repeat inside another while loop

Tags: c#

I'm making a Console application and I have one while loop to restart the whole program when the paycheck is calculated and another while loop to re-asks the questions about what type of paycheck the user receives if the input is wrong. But when I enter the incorrect option the question is asked again and the whole program restarts too. Is there a way to have the second while loop react separately from the first while loop?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WageCalc
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Variables
            string hourWorkedInput;
            string wageInput;
            double hourlyWage = 0.00;
            int hoursWorkedAWeek = 0;
            double payCheck;
            bool wageCalculated = false;
            bool AskQuestion = true;


            //Actual Code
            while (wageCalculated == false)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the Monthly Wage Calculator");
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter how much you are paid an hour");
                wageInput = Console.ReadLine();
                hourlyWage = Double.Parse(wageInput);
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter how many hours you work a week");
                hourWorkedInput = Console.ReadLine();
                hoursWorkedAWeek = Int32.Parse(hourWorkedInput);
                Console.WriteLine("Do you get paid (W)eekly or (B)iweekly?");
                string often = Console.ReadLine();

                //Repeats if input is incorrect
                while(AskQuestion)
                {
                    if (often == "W")
                    {
                        payCheck = hoursWorkedAWeek * hourlyWage;
                        Console.WriteLine("You will make {0} on every paycheck", payCheck);
                        Console.WriteLine("Would you like to Calculate another Paycheck?");
                        string repeat = Console.ReadLine();
                        switch (repeat)
                        {
                            case "Y":
                                wageCalculated = false;
                                break;
                            case "N":
                                wageCalculated = true;
                                break;
                            default:
                                wageCalculated = true;
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (often == "B")
                    {
                        payCheck = (hoursWorkedAWeek * 2) * hourlyWage;
                        Console.WriteLine("You will make {0} on every paycheck", payCheck);
                        Console.WriteLine("Would you like to Calculate another Paycheck?");
                        string repeat = Console.ReadLine();
                        switch (repeat)
                        {
                            case "Y":
                                wageCalculated = false;
                                break;
                            case "N":
                                wageCalculated = true;
                                break;
                            default:
                                wageCalculated = true;
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Please pick W or B");
                        AskQuestion = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So much unneeded code, wow

Comment: Please, if the comment isn't intended to give some sort of help do not post it. Thank you.

Comment: It is, I'm letting you know that we don't want to have to sort through your code to find the important bits. Do us a favor and help us help you, don't just copy-pasta your code from your IDE in here, that's lazy and rude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or you could make it a little more fun and simple

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{

   //Actual Code
   while (true)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the Monthly Wage Calculator");
      Console.WriteLine("Please enter how much you are paid an hour");

      double hourlyWage;
      while (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out hourlyWage))
         Console.WriteLine("You had one job, now answer the question properly");

      Console.WriteLine("Please enter how many hours you work a week");

      double hoursWorkedAWeek;
      while (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out hoursWorkedAWeek))
         Console.WriteLine("You had one job, now answer the question properly");

      Console.WriteLine("Do you get paid (W)eekly or (B)iweekly?");
      var often = Console.ReadLine();
      while (often != "W" && often != "B")
      {
         Console.WriteLine("You had one job, now answer the question properly");
         often = Console.ReadLine();
      }

      if (often == "W")
         Console.WriteLine($"You will make {hoursWorkedAWeek * hourlyWage} on every paycheck");
      else if (often == "B")
         Console.WriteLine($"You will make {hoursWorkedAWeek * 2 * hourlyWage} on every paycheck");

      Console.WriteLine("Would you like to play again Y/N?");

      var repeat = Console.ReadLine();
      while (repeat != "Y" && repeat != "N")
      {
         Console.WriteLine("You had one job, now answer the question properly");
         repeat = Console.ReadLine();
      }

      if (repeat == "N")
      {
         Console.WriteLine("Suit yourself, goodbye");
         break;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Is there a problem with declaring variables at the top or is it just personal preference?

Comment: @Recht88 No problem, just makes the code cleaner in some peoples opinions